# Did Angel Beats copy Haruhi?

Tags: angel-beats, haruhi-suzumiya

Both Angel Beats and The Melancholy of Haruhi Suzumiya feature a strong female lead as well as a "brigade." In Angel Beats, there is the SSS Brigade, and in Haruhi there is the SOS Brigade. Since Haruhi came first, is it possible that Angel Beats copied Haruhi?

Comment: The scenario of Angel Beats is the 'Key' work.
Key works 'Kanon' 'AIR' 'CLANNAD' are the masterpieces of Kyoto Animation.
And 'Haruhi' is masterpiece of Kyoto Animation too. I think the Kanon and AIR and CLANNAD has atmosphere similar.
Why Haruhi dont have?

Answer (score 6):

tl;dr - They share what literary types call "themes". Angel Beats and Haruhi are both "school anime", so they will more than likely share themes.

School anime is a theme, the "school club" and "strong female lead" are also themes. You will find these themes in many anime as you watch more of them. Another example of a "school anime" with a "strong female lead" that's president of a "school club" is Medaka Box.

I wouldn't say Medaka Box copied Haruhi or Angel Beats, though. Just as I wouldn't say Angel Beats copied Haruhi.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why they both use the term "brigade" to describe their group?

Comment: They both use the Japanese 団 _dan_. While "brigade" is a somewhat weird name for a group of people in English, "_dan_" is quite common in Japanese as a way of describing groups of people like the SOS/SSS "Brigades".

Comment: Although they might not have copied off each other, I suspect the similarities may be intentional. If you look at the five most important characters in *Angel Beats!* (ones at the graduation), Yuri = Haruhi, Otonashi = Kyon, Kanade = Yuki, Hinata = Mikuru (both abused by their leaders) and Naoi = Itsuki (both have esper-like powers).

Answer (score 0):

Probably, since the main girl in Angel Beats (can't remember her name) is pretty much just as annoying and bossy as Haruhi. Both animes also take place in high school and have loads of weird situations, so that makes them similar. I watched both shows a while back, but from memory, I don't think Angel Beats straight up copied Melancholy, but it probably took a lot of inspiration from it. The author might have been like, "Well, Melancholy is really popular, and especially the main character, Haruhi, so I might want to make my story a little bit like that so it'll sell..."

Comment: "the shows are similar" is different from "the shows copied each other"...